# Can I make sure observe callback in order?

Tags: design-patterns

Any way to get called observer fuction in order?

I have `ObserverFoo` class.

and both `ChildObserverA` and `ChildObserverB` inherited `ObserverFoo`.

the problem is the observer callback should be called from `ChildObserverA` first.

Because there's dependency between `ChildObserverA` and `ChildObserverB`.

is it any good pattern to make sure `ChildObserverA::Observe()` called first?

Comment: Sorry about my bad English. correcting my english is welcome!

Comment: "the problem is the observer callback should be called from ChildObserverA first" you only said what your expectation is but not your problem =.=

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are the one implementing the observer class, so you are the one to implement such guarantees.

If you store subscribers in a list as they come in and then iterate over that when sending out notifications the notifications will typically go out in subscription order.

But this strictly depends on how the container that holds the subscribers is implemented, and you haven't specified what programming language and framework (if any) you are using.